# Omit values when fitting (lmfit nan_policy)

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

Say I have a signal with an underlaying gauss and some noise. Fitting is of course no problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import lmfit
from lmfit.models import *

x = np.arange(100)
gauss = np.array(norm.pdf(x, 50, 10))
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.001, 100)
signal = gauss + noise
plt.plot(x, signal)

model = GaussianModel()

model.set_param_hint('amplitude', value = 0.5, min = 0.1, max = 10)
model.set_param_hint('center', value = 50, min = 20, max = 80)
model.set_param_hint('sigma', value = 10, min = 1, max = 50)
params = model.make_params()

fit = model.fit(signal, params, x = x)

plt.plot(x, signal)
plt.plot(x, fit.best_fit)
```

[image]

Now say for some arbitrary reason my signal is cutoff. Some part of my gaussian shaped signal is missing (some saturation effect). Fitting with the same procedure now leads to a wrong fit. It makes sense since the saturation values are taken into consideration.

```
signal_cutoff = [value if value < 0.025 else 0.025 for value in signal]

fit2 = model.fit(signal_cutoff, params, x = x)
plt.plot(x, signal_cutoff)
plt.plot(x, fit2.best_fit)
plt.ylim(0, 0.04)
```

[image]

My idea how to avoid this was to replace the saturation values with `None` and then perform the fit with the `nan_policy` set to `propagate`:

```
signal_cutoff_omitted = [value if value < 0.025 else None for value in signal_cutoff]
fit3 = model.fit(signal_cutoff_omitted, params, x = x, nan_policy = 'propagate')
plt.plot(x, signal_cutoff_omitted)
plt.plot(x, fit3.best_fit)
plt.ylim(0, 0.04)
```

[image]

As one can see the fit is just the initial values which is also shown in the fit report. Not sure what I am doing wrong or if this is even the right approach. Any ideas how to achieve what I am trying to do in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the points from the data to fit. Perhaps something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import lmfit
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel

x = np.arange(100)
gauss = np.array(norm.pdf(x, 50, 10))
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.001, 100)
signal = gauss + noise

# get indices for data points that are not saturated
not_saturated = np.where(signal < 0.025)[0]

x_good = x[not_saturated]
s_good = signal[not_saturated]


plt.plot(x, signal, '#AABBCC', marker='+', linewidth=0, label='all data')
plt.plot(x_good, s_good, '#880000', marker='o', linewidth=0, label='good data')

model = GaussianModel()
params = model.make_params(amplitude=0.5, center=48, sigma=15)

result = model.fit(s_good, params, x=x_good)
print(result.fit_report())
plt.plot(x_good, result.best_fit, 'k', label='fit')

# predict for saturated data
predict = result.eval(result.params, x=x)
plt.plot(x, predict, 'g', label='predict for saturated x')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which will print a report of:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gaussian)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 26
    # data points      = 81
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 7.9661e-05
    reduced chi-square = 1.0213e-06
    Akaike info crit   = -1114.40646
    Bayesian info crit = -1107.22312
[[Variables]]
    amplitude:  0.98074785 +/- 0.01877254 (1.91%) (init = 0.5)
    center:     49.9665431 +/- 0.11026782 (0.22%) (init = 48)
    sigma:      9.95029883 +/- 0.16996484 (1.71%) (init = 15)
    fwhm:       23.4311627 +/- 0.40023660 (1.71%) == '2.3548200*sigma'
    height:     0.03932161 +/- 0.00129373 (3.29%) == '0.3989423*amplitude/max(1e-15, sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(amplitude, sigma) = -0.649
```

and generate a plot like this:

[image]